# spring resources/** weird behavior

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having some weird behavior with getting resources from the server using spring.
i'll do my best to explane.

I am using the spring MVC resources like this:

> mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Everything works well until i try to get a page from a path that is more than one "/" from root.

For example:
i have a mapping

> ```
> @RequestMapping({"/","/home"})
> public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
>     return "landingpage";   
> }
> ```

Which returns the landing page with all resources i need (.js, images etc.)

But if i do this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/extraMapping"})
public class ExtraController {
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExtraController.class);

    @RequestMapping({"/{id}/overview"})
    public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model,  @PathVariable int id) {
        return "extradashboard";    
    }
}
```

I get 404 not found on all resources.
So there wont be any confusions, if i change  return "extradashboard" to return "landingpage"; the same thing happens. 404 not found.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved the problem by creating another resource mapping to the new controllers base mapping.
like so:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="extraMapping/{id}/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```